# WebDav: "The Parameter is Incorrect" will show on some folders that have "index.html"/"index.php"

Tags: windows, networking, webdav, mod-webdav

I tried to set up a WebDAV connection for me to upload my works to the web server easily. This is the code that I have in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/webdav.conf`.

```
DavLockDB /var/www/DavLock
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/webdav/
        Alias /html /var/www/html/
        <Directory /var/www/html/>
              Options Indexes MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
        <Location /html>
            DAV On
            ForceType None
            AuthType Digest
            AuthName DAV-upload
            AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/.htpasswd_html
            AuthDigestProvider file
            Require valid-user
         </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

The whole connection works, including reading and writing. However when I try to go in some of the folders, that contains "index.php" / "index.html", Windows just show up an error message like this:
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2rcB.png), which says that `The Parameter is Incorrect`. I tried to search the Internet and someone says that it is due to apache try to render the page as HTML/PHP. Therefore I tried to add `ForceType None` in the config but it is not working.

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently had the same problem. For me, setting `DirectoryIndex disabled` in the WebDAV directory fixed that.

Source: http://dimitar.me/upgrading-to-apache-2-4-will-prevent-webdav-listing-of-directories-containing-index-files/

Comment: Though I found the same solution on other site, but still thank!